# What's overriding the colorcolumn option in Vim?

Tags: vim

In my `_vimrc` file I have:

```
set colorcolumn=80
```

I'd like to disable/modify this but I can't. When I use 120 instead of 80 nothing changes, and when I delete this line the column still keeps highlighted. However, `:set colorcoumn=120` does work when I enter it manually in a Vim session. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `:verbose set colorcolumn` here?

Comment: Hmm. "last set from ~\vimfiles\bundle\python-mode\ftplugin\python\pymode.vim"

Comment: There is colorcolumn=+1 at the beggining.

Comment: https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/develop/doc/pymode.txt#L118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By giving `:verbose set colorcolumn`, you have received

```
       Last set from ~\vimfiles\bundle\python-mode\ftplugin\python\pymode.vim
```

The plugin file called `pymode.vim` has changed the value of colorcolumn to colorcolumn+1,  whenever you opened file through vim.

To overrride this behaviour,
You can give

```
   :au BufEnter *.* :set colorcolumn=120
```

in ~/.vimrc.

This will override your plugin's behavior.

(Other alternate solutions: you can remove the plugin if you don't want. Or, remove that line in the plugin if it doesn't affect anything in the functions.)